# Rail's end_of_month() method always return 30 as last date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time

I am using ruby 2.3.6 and rails 5.1 and want to return last month's last date. According to current time it should be May 31st,2019.

So i have used

```
DateTime.now.end_of_month.prev_month
```

and got

```
Sat, 30 May 2019 23:59:59 +0530
```

as response while it should be 31. I have also tried same for March and January. Any idea why this behaviour??

Comment: My bad, fixed that in title.

Comment: "Any idea why this behaviour?" – well, `DateTime.now.end_of_month` returns `30 Jun 2019` and calling `prev_month` turns that into `30 May 2019`. It's the expected behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
DateTime.now.prev_month.end_of_month
```

Just switch the last two calls

Answer (score 1):

`prev_month` is method which do not alter and take day or date into account and just get previous month.

You can verify it by using February month,

```
(DateTime.now.end_of_month - 4.month).prev_month
```